Flutter Web App on Firebase: different Environments for test and production
We develop an application in Flutter Web.
The application is deployed on Firebase. We use the mechanisms available there for user management and the Firestore to store configuration parameters (e.g. the access data for systems that are integrated).
We would now like to use a test environment and a productive environment as separate Firebase projects, as we have different users and configuration parameters for both environments.
We have defined corresponding targets for "test" and "prod" in the "firebase.json" and ".firebaserc" files.
However, only the firebase options for one environment can be set in firebase_options.dart.
Do you have any tips or ideas on how to implement something like this?
Many thanks in advance for your help!
Tom
We have already tried different ways with the 3 files (firebase.json, .firebaserc, firebase_options.dart). We have not succeeded in mapping the desired case.

you could create a new firebase_options_test.dart and refer to it when you initialise Firebase ? Untested but it seems logic to me

What you can do is have different firebase_options.dart files for different environments and place them in different locations(ideally under  dir). That way you can import the relevant firebase_options.dart file.

Is there a "good" way to use these different firebase_options.dart files in CI/CD? We're using Bitbucket here and don't want to create different packages (if possible).
